# How to use an Vanilla Javascript Class in a Vue Component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a laravel project which globally registers vue in the `app.js` file. Vue works in my project as I have it working in another part of my app. What makes this situation unique is I do not have somewhere, like a blade file, to pass my vue component through as a medium to be used. I have a vanilla js file and a vue component. I want to be able to use the methods created in my `test.js` file inside of my `testing.vue` file. I am simply trying to pass some data from my js to my vue and then `console.log()` it out to ensure the data is being passed properly. I do use `npm run dev` to compile assets. The code is pretty boiler plate at this point since my main objective right now is to just pass the data properly. I did confirm the import path as well and it is correct. Not sure why the `console.log()` is not showing in the browser. This is my current code:

Test.js

```
export class Test {
    testing() {
        console.log('this is a test');
    }
}
```

Testing.vue

```
<template>
  <div>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
import {Test} from '../../js/Test';

export default {
  name: 'Testing',
  mounted() {
    console.log(Test.testing());
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must create an **instance** of the `Test` class in order to use the method. In your `Testing.vue` file:

```
<template>
  <div>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import {Test} from '../../js/Test';

  export default {
    name: 'Testing',
    
    mounted() {
      // IMPORTANT to create instance of a class
      const myTestInstance = new Test();
      
      console.log(myTestInstance.testing());
    }
  }
</script>
```

The method `testing()` on class `Test` is not a static method and thus need object to invoke. Alternately, if you don't want to create object, then you can declare the method as static as shown below:

```
export class Test {
    static testing() {
        console.log('this is a test');
    }
}
```

You can then us it like this: `Test.testing()`.

Comment: I instantiated the `Test()` but when I check my browser console it is still not logging.

Comment: @pa-gw Since all that Test.testing() does is ```console.log('this is a test')```, you shouldn't have to call ```console.log(myTestInstance.testing());``` in ```mounted()```.  Just call ```myTestinstance.testing()```.  And this isn't a knock against Harshal.  With 10K+ reputation, obviously he knows what he is doing.

Comment: @Tim Yeah. I did notice that but left it unchanged as it doesn't cause any harm and kept the original code as much as possible. Ideally, that would first print string `this is a test` and then `undefined` for outer `console.log`.